# How to make dish drainer board from plywood shelf

Tags: drain, plywood

I'm making a shelf above my kitchen sink with intention of putting glasses there to dry off.

How can I treat plywood surface to make it into drainer board?
The sink and the shelf are inside oblique corner, so I can't just buy a dish rack.

Something like [image: this] would work for me, but I need it trapezium-shaped.

Answer (score 1):

Several coats of polyurethane would work. Acrylic likewise. Epoxy would work. Per @DMoore's comment on some other question, redguard would do, but would stink for several weeks (as might the epoxy, depending on epoxy formulation.)

Be sure to coat both top and bottom and especially edges. Top and bottom to reduce warpage that you'd be prone to if you only coat one side, and edges since plywood likes to fall apart if moisture gets in between the layers.

You could also possibly build this from "solid surface countertop" material - 1/2" thick plastic, pretty much.

Comment: re: the last suggestion, most tile shops sell 'corner shelves' for showers. Essentially solid surface counter top pre-formed for usage in corners.

Answer (score 0):

It may be over kill, but you can use something like Marine Varnish. Super thick coating will work great and this is used on wooden counter tops (not butcher blocks) to keep the wood dry.

[http://www.amazon.com/Rust-Oleum-207008-Marine-Varnish-1-Quart/dp/B000C011CE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000C011CE)